# try catch has an influence in char** return values

Tags: c++, char, return, try-catch

```
char **test()
{
    char *a[3];
    a[0] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) *3);
    a[1] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) *3);
    a[0] = "aa";
    a[1] = "bb";
    return a;
}   

//main
try{
    char **  a;
    a = test();
    cout << a[0] << " " << a[1];
}
catch(std::exception){}
```

compiled in vs2008, this program failed to output "bb", but after I remove the try catch block, it turned out to be "aa bb" which is true. The reason and solution ?

Comment: Apart from the memory leaks, was there a specific point to this (or maybe I just missed it once I saw those).? You're returning the address of a local variable, which is out of scope when you eval `a[]` in your main. Not sure if that is your intention, but it is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: why are we using malloc in c++?

Comment: @andre because he can, and `<cstdlib>` doesn't throw a `#error` as a macro replacement when you do so (yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program has undefined behavior, because you are returning a pointer to a local. You need to allocate the `a` array with `malloc` in order to fix the problem:

```
char **test() {
    char **a = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 2);
    a[0] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) *3);
    a[1] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) *3);
    strcpy(a[0], "aa");
    strcpy(a[1], "bb");
    return a;
}
```

Of course now you are fully responsible for releasing all that `malloc`-ed memory in your `main`, to avoid memory leaks (you were already on the hook for that with your implementation; now you simply need to add the third `free` to the caller).

The discrepancies that you see are most likely due to the differences of stack management with and without a `try`/`catch` block. It appears that without `try`/`catch` the data in the local remains available for you to print, even though it is no longer legal to reference it after the return of the `test()` function.

Comment: I'd prefer to see a solution that doesn't introduce a third memory leak; but +1 for explaining the immediate problem.

Comment: LOL memory leaks still functional and fully intact =P

Comment: @MikeSeymour The leak (actually, two leaks) were there already, because OP's `main` failed to `free` the two strings inside the returned array. Thanks for pointing it out, though - I edited the answer to reflect the need to free the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: returning a pointer to a local array. This is destroyed when the function returns, and using the pointer after that gives undefined behaviour.

Problem 2: Explicit memory management, and overwriting the pointers to allocated memory with pointers to string literals. The memory you allocate is leaked; and if you try to modify the literals you'll get more undefined behaviour.

Assuming you're writing C++, not C, the following will fix both problems:

```
std::vector<std::string> test() {return {"aa", "bb"};}
```